# Visual Studio Executing Cell- Which cell is being executed?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have recently started using VS code, moved from Jupyter notebook. When I run a notebook in visual studio , in the status bar I get a notification Executing cells. Is there a way to find out in Visual studio code which cell is being executed?